# Offline Folders in Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have a Synology File Server. When I connect to it using a Windows 10 Machine, I am able to right click on a folder and select "Always available offline".

When I am on a server running Windows Server 2016, that option is not available.

According to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/974603/how-to-configure-ftp-for-iis-7-0-or-higher-in-a-windows-server-2008-or), I need to add the 'Desktop Experience' feature before File Sync is available - however, I do not see that Feature in the list of available features.

How can I get offline files to work in Server 2016?

Comment: Looks like desktop experience is always installed with a server 2016 Full installation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/getting-started-with-server-with-desktop-experience

Comment: Just curious. I've never experienced this issue because I have never had a need to use offline files on a server? What purpose does this serve? Servers are typically not user accessed, unless they are terminal servers, and they are online all the time, so no use for offline files.

Comment: Hey @Appleoddity - I am running IIS with shared configuration files that are stored on the network drives.  Alot of articles out there suggest that you use the Offline Files feature so that if your drive is unreachable for any reason, the IIS servers will still be able to get the cached configuration files -

Comment: @Appleoddity - I have read that abou tthe Desktop experience being part of it as well - however, the Offline Files option still doesn't seem like its available;

Answer (score 0):

> According to this article, I need to add the 'Desktop Experience'
>   feature before File Sync is available - however, I do not see that
>   Feature in the list of available features

When you install Windows Server 2016 using the Setup wizard, you can choose between **Windows Server 2016** and **Windows Server (Server with Desktop Experience)**. The Server with Desktop Experience option is the Windows Server 2016 equivalent of the Full installation option available in Windows Server 2012 R2 with the Desktop Experience feature installed. If you do not make a choice in the Setup wizard, Windows Server 2016 is installed; this is the Server Core installation option.

Unlike some previous releases of Windows Server, ***you cannot convert
between Server Core and Server with Desktop Experience after
installation***. If you install Server with Desktop Experience and later
decide to use Server Core, you should do a fresh installation.

[Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/getting-started-with-server-with-desktop-experience)

> How can I get offline files to work in Server 2016?

From the doc the support in server OS was up to 2012R2 on what I see.

<s>In case the doc lie, Just make sure the folder is set in CSC, not CA in example.</s>

See the red checkbox in that picture:

**Edit**: striked the last reference, the share is not hosted on a windows.

[image]

Comment: All of my servers are installed as "Windows Server (Server with Desktop Experience)", however, I don't see File Sync anywhere - where do you see documentation saying that it is no longer supported?